# How to escape characters in DOM elements

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I tried to set CSS based on a condition. but inside quotes. I get a syntax error. Can any one help me out to find the solution?

```html
<div>
  <span ng-class='{\' rdng-error-rate\ ': test}'>#=sum#</span> 
</div>
```

This is my actual code:

```
{
  field: "errorRate",
  title: "ERROR RATE",
  footerTemplate: "<div ng-class="{'rdng-error-rate': #=sum# }"> #=sum# </div>"
}
```

Comment: Please provide some codes and some more details.

Comment: Some code will be better.

Comment: `#LearnToPostCorrectly`

Comment: This is my actual code
{ field: "errorRate", title:"ERROR RATE", footerTemplate: "<div ng-class="{'rdng-error-rate': #=sum# }"> #=sum# </div>"}

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use this way?

```
ng-class='{"rdng-error-rate": "test"}'
```

JSON object literals are meant to have `"` in their strings.

Comment: I tried this one but this is not working for me
My actual code is
footerTemplate: "<div ng-class={ 'rdng-error-rate': dataItem.requestsFailed > 0} > #=value# </div>"

Comment: @Dharmarajan Does it include the two "s?

Comment: Yes. I tried this also
{ field: "errorRate", title:"ERROR RATE", footerTemplate: "<div ng-class="{'rdng-error-rate': #=sum# }"> #=sum# </div>"}

Answer (score -1):

Try to use one of this `&` `<` `>` `-`

or do some changes in your actual code

```
  {
  field: "errorRate";
  title: "ERROR RATE";
  footerTemplate: "<div ng-class="{'rdng-error-rate': "#=sum#" }"> #=sum</div>";
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank You, person needing the answer will know by himself and if he or she doesn't, he'll ask it again, no need to provide copy pasted code and description from internet

Comment: Thanks @AakashShah. I found the issue. After removing '-' in css class it is working. `rdngerrorrate`
do you have any idea why '-' is throwing a parse error?

Comment: Not much @Dharmarajan but I guess its happening due to the angularjs and kendoui structure and the way they interact